# Getting started with Java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I'm a C++ programmer learning Java, and I'm having a couple of logistical issues. I was able to recreate the standard "Hello, world!", but now I need to implement a class (well, besides the fact the the Hello program is in a class, too...Java is weird) and test it.

I defined a small class called Node with a couple of integer fields and a simple member function (in Node.java), so my silly question is, "How do I create a place to try it out in another file?" (It's remarkable how so many sources seem to assume that you know these little details)

I'm assuming I'll need a Main.java, with a class Main inside it...plus a "public static void Main(.." method. But how do I access this node class, which is in the same directory? Java doesn't seem to have "#include" ...

Comment: *"Java doesn't seem to have "#include""*, no, Java has `import` instead. I'd suggest you have a read through [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), starting with the basics ;)

Comment: Voting to close - what you need is an introductory Java text.

Comment: _(It's remarkable how so many sources seem to assume that you know these little details)_ Why don't you start with a getting started guide. Everyone should start from the beginning some day.

Comment: Read official docs. Java is more understandable then c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Node` class and `Main` class exist within the same package, then you don't need to specify an `import` for the class.  All classes in the same package are automatically included (more or less).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node node = new Node();
    }
}
```

If the `Node` or `Main` are in different packages, then you need to use `import`.

So, if `Node` was in `awesome.node` package, you're code would look more like...

```
import awesome.node.Node;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node node = new Node();
    }
}
```

I'd take a closer look at the [Packages trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question.

Comment: We all gotta start some where